# Neo4j count(*) returning wrong value

Tags: neo4j

The query in question is:

```
MATCH (p1:Politician)-[r1:mentioned_by]->(c:Channel {name: "Telefe Noticias"})<-[r2:mentioned_by {video_id: r1.video_id}]-(p2:Politician)
WHERE p1.fullname < p2.fullname  
RETURN COUNT(*) AS totalMentions
```

Neo4j is returning 364 but there are 59 records and I can't understand why.

Comment: If you take off COUNT(*) and return p1, p2, r1.video_id, r2.video_id ORDER BY p1.fullname, p2.fullname, r1.video_id, r2.video_id can you see which patterns are being duplicated?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have duplicates and also permutations/combinations of how the politicians are ordered and sequenced. If the latter is true, you need to address it in the query. Here's one strategy for doing so:

```
MATCH (p1:Politician)-[r1:mentioned_by]->(c:Channel {name: "Telefe Noticias"})<-[r2:mentioned_by {video_id: r1.video_id}]-(p2:Politician)
with case when p1.fullname < p2.fullname then p1.fullname else p2.fullname end as pols1,
case when p2.fullname < p1.fullname then p2.fullname else p1.fullname end as pols2
with collect(pols1 + pols2) as cPols 
RETURN size(cPols) AS totalMentions
```

You may need distinct in the collect statement or use an [apoc.coll function](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.coll/) to flatten the collection.

You can also modify this to get the count for each politician, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
    MATCH (p1:Politician)-[r1:mentioned_by]->(c:Channel {name: "${channelName}"})<-[r2:mentioned_by {video_id: r1.video_id}]-(p2:Politician)
    WHERE p1.fullname < p2.fullname 
    WITH DISTINCT p1.fullname AS x, p2.fullname AS y
    RETURN COUNT(*) AS rows
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).